# Cannot submit form to controller zend framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I create a from statically in HTML file in view project which is inside the module visit.
I want the controller to handle the request occur when submitting the form

```
 <form action="addVisit" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="number"/>
 <input type="submit" name="save"/>
```

The structure of the project is

module  visits

controller Visits and it has action addVisit

when submitting the form an error occur, the url becomes like this when submitting the form

```
http://localhost/zendApps/InspectionSys/public/visits/visits/VisitsController/addVisit
```

in the controller there is a function action

```
 public function addVisitAction()
{
            echo 'here';
}
```

what should I do ?

Comment: What happened with your last question? Haven't you fixed the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you might reconsider camel caseing your actions `addVisitAction()` because if you do then you have to deal with view file names like `add-visit.phtml` I think it will affect urls as well, I find it simpler just to leave action names as lowercase `addvisitAction()`, this might be part of what's amiss.

Next identify your form actions as `/module/controller/action` (if you are not using modules you can omit that param), so your action should at least be `/visits/visits/addvisit` or `/visits/visits/add-visit` (not quite sure which will work properly) .

also when using html forms that were not generated by Zend_Form you can access the values using `$this->getParams()` or `$this->getParam('paramName')` instead of `$this->getValues()`.